# OS X - read permission on NTFS drive

Tags: macos, permissions, ntfs, file-permissions

I'm on OS X Mountain Lion and I try to copy a folder from an NTFS formatted usb drive, which I stored there from a Windows 7 computer.

The NTFS drive is mounted as read only in Mountain Lion, which is okay. But if I try to copy the folder onto my harddisk, I get the error "The operation can't be completed because you don't have permission to access some of the items." no additional information.

as it is read-only, I can't use 'fix permissions' from disk utility.

Can someone explain the issue and how to resolve it?